# Brake mounting points very close to the rim

Tags: rim-brake

I have a bike that came originally with roller brakes. I would like to remove the roller brakes and install rim brakes instead.

For the rear wheel (this question is only about the rear wheel) there is what, to my inexperienced eye, look like mounting points for rim brakes. The problem, however, is that they are almost at the same height as the rim, only about 1 cm above of it. I haven't found a brake that would fit this geometry, and I'm not even sure how such a brake would work (it would be a kind of U-brake but the pads would travel a long way upwards for a short movement inwards).

Is there a brake that would fit here? And if not, are these mounting points actually *not* intended for brakes? Maybe just for holding cables?

A caliper brake is not an option, as there's no mounting point for it.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They're for a wheel lock, aka ring lock or Dutch lock.

If the bike came with the lower end Shimano roller brakes (Nexus) and you're looking this direction because they were inadequate, probably what makes the most sense is go to the higher end ones because they're much stronger.

Unless there's anything else useful happening for brake mounting that the photo doesn't show on the chainstays or laterals, you would be looking at getting the frame modified for any kind of rim brake mounting.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I want to get rid of these particular brakes is because they introduce noticeable drag even when not engaged. If I'm really stuck with them, I guess I'll try to clean and regrease, or failing that, getting better ones as you suggest